# What are the properties I should look for in running shoes?

Tags: shoes, running

I'm an amateur runner, but I've been constantly doing it for a year or so.

My philosophy is to first start doing something before beginning to spend and invest a lot of money in that something.
Applies to any hobby of mine and it also did with running.

I run close to an hour.
And often I stop because my bones and my articulations start to hurt a bit.
Last year I had Achilles tendonitis and I want to avoid that in the future.

From what I've learned researching online, it seems that I'm close to the threshold where running shoes really start to matter if you don't want to hurt yourself badly.

All the tracks around where I live are on asphalt.
I don't believe in the barefoot-movement so I don't want light shoes or anything like that.
I want shoes that will amortize most of the shock the legs get at each step and keep my knees and tendons safe.

What should I be looking for in running shoes?

Comment: *I run close to an hour. And often I stop because my bones and my articulations start to hurt a bit. Last year I had Achilles tendonitis and I want to avoid that in the future.*  What I have observed in my running sessions which were more like a Long-Distance Prep sessions, is You face such a problem that you stated above, is more likely because you are running lower below your adaptable pace/tempo. And, if you start to feel a little heavier at your chest, then probably you are sprinting to fast. Having said these, the two problems discussed here **may**(not must) be caused for stated reasons.

Comment: The pace-related feelings that you described match mine pretty well. Thanks for those tips. I didn't know what they meant.

Comment: @PaulIrofti, consider asking on Physical Fitness SE (http://fitness.stackexchange.com/), it's wisited by more runners, and you question almost doesn't concern Outdoors at all.

Comment: related: http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/5387/what-scientific-evidence-is-there-about-the-causes-and-prevention-of-running-inj

Answer (score 4):

For that matter why don't you get a Jogger Shoe for you?
When I had been to a running exped, I was told to get shoes with following Props:

1. Got to have a double inner sole. (This implies that you get a shoe of size which is slightly bigger than you normal shoe size). This help you to expand and contract the skin, muscles of feet.
2. Make sure that they are not heavy and doesn't have a too hard sole.
3. Make sure that they don't have a very hard (synthetics/steel like DMS have) Toe.
4. Make sure that they have a Fabric which will be such that your feet will get air.

Comment: with such a shoe, i have managed to complete a running exped of 240 km in 6 days

Answer (score 4):

Make sure the problem is in the shoes first.

First, if you run on asphalt, try running on dirt trails. They are softer and provide much less shock to your joints.

Second, make sure your running technic is correct. I would recommend [the book from a world champion Gordon Pirie](http://www.scribd.com/doc/13695/Gordon-Piries-Running-Fast-and-Injury-Free), which is very understandable by a non-professional runner. One basic idea from the book is that you should land on your toe, not on your heel. This introduces another joint to participate in shock absorbtion, distributing the force more evenly. I don't claim that this is the only right technic, but it does work. The book has advice on running shoes too, but they are quite different from what you usually hear from the adverticements.

I have had the same problem too, and running on the dirt + landing on my toe (well, more on my toe, than on my heel) pushed the limit from 1 our to 2+ hours.

Comment: +1 for landing on toe thing! I will give it a try. I still 80/100 times land on my heel and this causes pain in my heel after I stop running!